# Objective-C atomic operations/locking access to myLocation property in Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, atomic, synchronize, google-maps-sdk-ios

This is partly a question regarding the Google Maps SDK in iOS, though perhaps mostly a question about atomic operations in Objective-C.

In my app, I wish to draw a GMSPolyline on a map between the user's current location and a selected destination.  I can retrieve the user's current location using the `myLocation` property on a `GMSMapView`.  According to the documentation for `myLocation`:

> If My Location is enabled, reveals where the user location dot is
>   being drawn.
>
> If it is disabled, or it is enabled but no location data is available,
>   this will be nil. This property is observable using KVO.

I have code to draw the polyline which takes the form:

```
if (myMapView.myLocation) {
    // draw polyline between myMapView.myLocation and the selected destination
}
```

My concern is that, however remote the possibility, that between the check `if (myMapView.myLocation)` and drawing the polyline `// draw polyline between myMapView.myLocation and the selected destination`, `myMapView.myLocation` might become `nil` if the location is lost at an inopportune moment.

So my question is, in Objective-C, is there a way for me to wrap both the check that `myMapView.myLocation` is not nil and drawing the polyline into an operation which locks access to `myMapView.myLocation`, so it can't be changed after the check but before attempting to draw the polyline.  If Objective-C does provide a mechanism, what affect does this have if the Google library *does* attempt to update `myLocation` while it is locked?  Does the update just get queued until I've finished drawing the polyline and release the lock?

So I guess this is mostly a question about atomic transactions in Objective-C, in the context of the Google Maps library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically for Objective C, but based on locking in other languages, I think what you want could only work if it was done in cooperation with the third-party library (ie Google Maps).

So for example if you were to somehow lock `myMapView.myLocation` while using it, this would only work if the Google Maps SDK also promised to lock it while modifying it, with the same lock object that you are using. Since `myMapView.myLocation` can be `nil`, this would be unlikely to work since you couldn't use a `nil` object as the 'key' to lock.

Similarly if you could lock the entire `GMSMapView`, such that none of its properties could change while the lock was held, this could only work if the Google Maps SDK promised to take the same lock before making any modifications.

In general, it's probably not a good idea to lock arbitrary objects from third-party libraries, as this might interfere with that library's own synchronization (unless the library explicitly offers this as part of its interface). Vice versa, when writing a library for use by third parties, it's best not to implement internal locking on objects which the library makes public - instead locking should usually be implementated on internal objects - just in case a user of the library tries to lock the public object.

In your case though, you could avoid the problem by doing this:

```
CLLocation* location = myMapView.myLocation;
if (location) 
{
    // draw polyline between location and the selected destination
}
```

That way even if the map view sets its `.myLocation` property to `nil` in between your check and your draw, you will still have a reference to the `CLLocation`, which can't be set to `nil`.

Note though that [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view) says:

> GMSMapView can only be read and modified from the main thread, similar
>   to all UIKit objects. Calling these methods from another thread will
>   result in an exception or undefined behavior.

It seems likely that `GMSMapView` would honour the same requirement and so only modify its public properties from the main thread. So if your code is running in the main thread (which it has to), its unlikely that the map view's properties will change in the middle of your code running.